# HPC pack 2008 sdk doesn't add any parallelism into code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

I've started to learn parallel programming with mpi.
For that I installed HPC pack 2008 sdk in my Win 10 (64 bit)

The problem is that it doesn't add any parallelism into my code.
For example I am starting

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "omp.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Print\n");
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(12)
    {
        printf("Print\n");
    }
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    {
        printf("Print\n");
    }
    printf("Print\n");
}
```

with next command in terminal:

/path_to_mpiexec/mpiexec.exe -n 1 /path_to_exe_file/sample.exe

and the output is just 4 "Print" strings.

If i am using -n 4 then it just 12 "Print" strings while i should be more.

About system configuration:
I am using Visual Studio 2015
In project setting I set :

[Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F6zN.png)

And

[Debug settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yPH9.png)

Also in Linker -> Input settings I added msmpi.lib

Comment: Have you tried a real MPI hello world instead of this?

Comment: MPI != OpenMP..

Comment: You generally need to pass a flag to the C compiler in order to enable OpenMP support (otherwise `#pragma omp ...` are ignored, with or without a warning message).